# How to use jquery to select CSS3 element & change it

Tags: jquery

**CSS**

```
.block{
-moz-linear-gradient(left, #e5e5e5 0%, #000000 100%);
}
```

Change  to

```
-moz-linear-gradient(left, #e5e5e5 50%, #000000 100%);
```

**html**

```
<div class="block" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
```

I don't want to replace all of the style.Because I need to give user choose 1-100
then only change the % ,so how to select the % element & change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var area = 'left';
var color1 = '#e5e5e5';
var percentage1 = '50%';
var color2 = '#000000';
var percentage2 = '100%';
$('.block').css('background-image', '-moz-linear-gradient(' + area + ', ' + color1 + ' ' + percentage1 +', ' + color2 + ' ' + percentage2  + ')');
```

Comment: This is okay in only change %,but if user has been changed 'top',use this script will replace it...then back to 'left'

Answer (score 0):

```
var percentage = "50%"; //set to user input
$("div.block").css("background", "-moz-linear-gradient(left, #e5e5e5 "+percentage+", #000000 100%)");
```

There's no way to set the percentage directly, but this should work.

Comment: The same problem.If user has been changed 'top',use this script will replace it...then back to 'left'